# Не отправляется почта mail() с сервера

Tags: php, сервер, email

Пробую вот так:

```
<?php
    if(!mail("куда отправляем", "я письмо", "я сообщение"))
        echo 'не пашет ';
?>
```

Нажимаю <kbd>Enter</kbd>, пишет `не пашет`. Пробовал на другом хостинге всё работает. Что делать? Обращаться в тех поддержку? Или самому что-то исправлять?

Comment: Скорее всего, вы не подняли почтовый сервер на своем хосте.

Comment: А логи php смотрели? Обычно либо sendmail не настроен, либо прав нету, либо вообще он отсутствует

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы пользуетесь услугами обычного хостинга, то данная функция должна поставляться хостером. Вам нужно задать вопрос в техподдержку.

Если это VPS сервер, и его администрированием занимаетесь Вы, лучше воспользоватся услугами профессиональных администраторов, для настройки `sendmail`. Это достаточно сложный процесс. Если хотите попробовать сами, то следует настроить `exim`, например. Статья по настройке - [вот](http://linux-notes.org/ustanovka-exim-na-debian-ubuntu-mint/).

**Как проверить?**

Заходите в каталог `/var/log` ищете там файл `mail`, в нем содержатся ошибки, если sendmail настроен.

Ещё рекомендую посмотреть в файлу `error.log`, он обычно лежит в `/var/log/apache/error.log`. В этом файле, возможно, будут какие-либо ошибки.

Если есть доступ к файлу `php.ini`, посмотрите параметр `sendmail_path`, возможно его путь указан не верно. Путь к sendmail можно посмотреть командой `which sendmail`. Пример правильных параметров:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -F"Full Name" -f'emailaddress@example.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Дополнение  к ответу @GrayHoax

Это в случае если хостер не может\ не хочет предоставить свой почтовый сервер.

Что бы работала отправка почты нужно:

1. Поднять свой smtp сервер
2. Использовать smtp сервера например google или yandex

Скрипт взять с англоязычной версии

```
// Pear Mail Library
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = '<from.gmail.com>';
$to = '<to.yahoo.com>';
$subject = 'Hi!';
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'johndoe@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'passwordxxx'
    ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}
```