# Не работает форма php Contact на сайте

Tags: php, form

Сделал Contact форму ввев свою почту, не отправляется. Может ли это быть из за того, что сайт без домена?
В настройках Gmail предоставлен доступ к отправке письма на почту.

**Contact.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Photography</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Contact.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="background">
      <h1 class="logo">Name</h1>
      <h3 class="sub_logo">Photography</h3>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="Contact.html" class="active">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="main-part">

      <img src="img/wheel.jpg" alt="Car wheel" oncontextmenu="return false;">

      <div class="contact-title">
        <h1>Contact</h1>
        <h2>Fill the form below</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-form">
        <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="">
          <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" required>
          <br>
          <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" required>
          <br>
          <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" row="4" required></textarea>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" class="form-control submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Contact.css**

```
*{
  font-family: "montserrat", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #222;
}

.main-part {
  transform: translateY(-8%);
  height: 1000px;
  width: auto;
}

.main-part img {
  opacity: 30%;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1080px;
  width: 100%;
}

.background {
  background: #333;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
 
.background h1.logo {
  font-size: 29px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  transform: translateY(80%);
  color: #e3e3e3;
}

.background h3.sub_logo {
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  transform: translateY(170%);
  color: #e3e3e3;
}

.background nav {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
}

.background ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
  transform: translateY(135%);
}

.background ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.background ul li a,
.background ul li a:after {
  transition: all .3s;
}

.background ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.background ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  content: ".";
  color: transparent;
  background: #aaa;
  height: 1px;
}

.background ul li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.background ul li a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.background ul li a.active:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  content: ".";
  color: transparent;
  height: 1px;
}

.background ul li a.active:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.contact-title {
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-title h1 {
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 10px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(620%)
}

.contact-title h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  transform: translateY(600%);
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-form {
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  color: #fff;
}

input {
  height: 45px;
}

.form-control {
  width: 600px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form .submit {
  background: #ff5722;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

form .submit:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Contact.php**

```
<?php
    include "Contact.html";

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_from = 'Contact.html';

    $email_subject = 'New form Submission';

    $email_body = 'User name: $name.\n'.
                  'User email: $visitor_email.\n'.
                  'User Message: $message.\n';

    $to = '********@gmail.com';

    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

    header("Location: Contact.html");
?>
```

Comment: smtp поднят на сервере?

Comment: плохо понимаю что это. $from $to?

Comment: вы выполняете код отправки письма, но ведь вам нужно с какого-то адреса отправить его

Comment: да, у меня весь сайт в формаьах html & css. в том дело что я не запускал сервер. делал форму с видео-урока, там вроде бы все было нормально. в форму вписывается имэйл и приходит сообщение на почту

Comment: у вас не произойдет отправки в таком случае. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417270/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B0-mail-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: т е мне просто нужно поднять сайт на сервер и почтовый сервер?

Comment: именно. еще как вариант можно отправлять через свой почтовый ящик (google/yandex). изучите https://codernotes.ru/articles/php/otpravka-pisem-s-pomoshhyu-phpmailer.html